# Mysql replace a part from search (replace by pattern)

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a column containing next text:

```
..some text1 <a href="http://url_1_begin<a href="http://url2">_url_1_middle_</a>url_1_end"> some text2 </a> some text3..
```

How can I delete inner < a >< /a > tag?

Does exist SQL query to recieve

```
..some text1 <a href="http://url_1_begin_url_1_middleurl_1_end"> some text2 </a> some text3..
```

text and url's href are different for each row

Comment: Looks like string manipulation to me. Use combinations of INSTR and SUBSTR or SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the parts you want and remove the parts you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query-

```
SET @a = "..some text1 <a href=\"http://url_1_begin<a href=\"http://url2\">_url_1_middle_</a>url_1_end\"> some text2 </a> some text3..";

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@a,"<a href","href"),"</a>",'');
```